# How can I change the time between sprites in 2D animations on Unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I've got a 2D animation with 3 sprites (images). When I play, the animation is very fast, and I'd like to know if it's possible to change the time between the sprites

If it is, how can I do it?
And if it's not, how can I solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do that.

1. Move the keyframes away from each other.
2. Reduce the sample rate of animation. (look at top left part of animation panel)
3. Select a state in animator and change Speed in inspector
4. Reduce Time.timeScale

Comment: Okey the 3rd one worked, thanks. Gonna mark it as correct in 5 minutes!

Comment: this is a very useful answer